# Cannot make the KeyFrame vary in Timeline JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, timeline, keyframe

I'm making a reaction time application and I need to display this in the GUI so I need to use a Timeline to do this. I have made everything work with the Timeline, other than allowing the time between KeyFrames to be variable.

In the code below, I managed to make it change after the first KeyFrame (so there is no wait, and then a wait time of 'waitTime' seconds). It then uses the value of 'waitTime' and keeps the time between KeyFrames constant from here. In the code is what I am doing to change the variable 'waitTime'. I am just unsure how I can change the KeyFrame time. I think I need a recursive way of doing this but have not yet been able to find anything anywhere on this topic.

```
double waitTime;

    Timeline attackChanger = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        
        
        //randomly generate attack
        if(isCountdown = true){
            int randI = rand.nextInt(10);
            waitTime = randI;
            System.out.println(waitTime);
            String attack = utils.getRandomAttack();
            attackLabel.setText(attack);
        }
        
        
    }
}), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(waitTime)));
```

Thank you in advance for any answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you start the `Timeline` the `KeyFrame`s are fixed. Even if they were not there's no passing of primitive types by reference in java, i.e. `Duration.seconds(waitTime)` returns a `Duration` object with constant duration no matter what you do to `waitTime` later. While the animation is running modifying the list of `KeyFrame`s does not have any effect either.

The probably best way of going about this would be to adjust the `rate` property of the timeline according to the new value.

Assuming you use

```
attackChanger.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
```

on your animation:

```
Timeline attackChanger = new Timeline();
attackChanger.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        
        
        //randomly generate attack
        if(isCountdown = true){
            int randI;

            // we need treat 0 immediately to avoid
            // setting the rate to infinity
            // note: in this case only a single
            // text value will be displayed and you probably should
            // go with (rand.nextInt(9) + 1) to generate values between
            // 1 and 9 (inclusive)
            // I keep it this way though because of the console output
            // and possible side effects of utils.getRandomAttack()
            do {
                randI = rand.nextInt(10);
                waitTime = randI;
                System.out.println(waitTime);
                String attack = utils.getRandomAttack();
                attackLabel.setText(attack);
            } while (randI == 0);

            // (effective cycle duration) = (standard duration) / rate
            attackChanger.setRate(1d / randI);
        }
        
        
    }
}), new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));
attackChanger.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

//make sure `waitTime` is not 0 at this point
attackChanger.setRate(1d / waitTime);
```

Comment: interesting .. always thought that all state properties are fixed during a run (and stop-change-restart the only approach) My learn item of the day :)